# Not able to remove ^M characters in a file - shell script

Tags: shell

I'm not able to remove the special character from file.

File Contents : a.lst

errordetails^M
grd^M
gpr^M

sed "s/^M//" a.lst > b.lst

b.lst also contains the special character

Comment: You need to escape (ie: \\) in front of special characters.

Comment: I want 'sed' to be run in a shell script, not by opening it through 'vi' editor.

Comment: ^M is not a literal ^ + M, instead use the following key combinations to get the character: ctrl+v+m

Comment: `dos2unix file`. Good luck.

Comment: user3684156:  Not literally hit the escape button.  The \ is called escape.

Comment: sed "s/\^M//" a.lst > b.lst is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -ibak 's/\^M//g' a.lst`

`-i` is to modify a.lst directly, `bak` is to backup your original file

(`\\`) back slash is to escape the specific character ^

`^` means the beginning of a line, which you need to escape it.

`g` is a global flag, for example "^M123^Mabcd^M", you can only remove the 1st "^M" without the global flag.

Edit:

```
echo "errordetails^M grd^M gpr^M" | sed 's/\^M//g'
errordetails  grd  gpr
```

Comment: Looks sed -ibak is not in my environment. 

sed: illegal option -- i
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

Comment: @user3684156 keep your `sed 'command-line'  input.txt > output.txt` style, it works fine, I preferred -ibak, so provided it :)

Comment: sed 's/\^M//g' inoput.txt > output.txt also fails.

Comment: it fails in the bash script or shell?

Comment: Fails in Shell script

Comment: I tried opening the file through vi editor, even then it fails.
vi input.txt

Comment: Tried sed 's/^M//g' input.txt > output.txt, still no outcome.

Comment: @user3684156  I dont know how it does not work for you, check the Edit part in my answer, it should be clear enough